# Display images dynamically from json file where path is kept in react js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I created a json file where I keep title, content and url to svg icons which I use in React component to render UI. Unfortunately, somehow the images do not show up, the rest of the information stored in the json file yes is shown. Could you help me point out what am I doing wrong? Below you'll find screenshot if my project tree, part of my json file and code that I use to render the UI with the data stored in the json file.
[image]

The Menu.js component code:

```
    import React from 'react'
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import menuTiles from '../files/menuTiles.json';
import '../styles/style.css';
function Menu(){
    return (
        <main>
            <div className="container fluid">
                <div className="row justify-content-center"><h3>Scegli il menu oppure cercha qui per categorie</h3></div>
                <div className="div-menu-style">
                    {
                        menuTiles.map((menuDetail,index)=>{
                            return(
                                <div key={menuDetail.id}>
                                <a className="link-style" href="#">
                                    <div className="tile-style row">
                                    <div col="3"><img className="img-style"src={menuDetail.imgSrc} /></div>
                                    <div col="9">
                                    <h4>{menuDetail.title}</h4>
                                    <p>{menuDetail.content}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            )
                            
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}
export default Menu
```

Comment: It's most likely that the routes to the images are not correct. When you go to ```http://localhost:3000/musical-notes.svg``` can you see the image? 
I think you might be better off defining the mapping for the images, where key is a name of it and value would be an image. Then in you json you can store the key and in render just look it up in the map and pass the image to img tag

Comment: Is the image path correct? If you inspect the HTML, is the img src correct an can you browser navigate to that image url?

Comment: When I go to the url that you provided I do not see the images. In developer tools I can see the src attribute is equal to <img class="img-style" src="./musical-notes.svg">

Answer (score 0):

svg icons and files directory are not in same level. so you you should access icons directory from files directory like this `./icons/musical-notes.svg`. change like this.

```
{ imageSrc: "./icons/musical-notes.svg" }
```

Comment: It didn't solve the issue. I still do not have images displayed